# Proving inequality, then use comparison test for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

My problem is formulated like this: Given that both $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^2$ converges, establish the convergence (implies that it converges?) of the following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}| $$

My idea is this: If $0 \leq |a_{n}b_{n}| \leq a_{n}^2 + b_{n}^2$ for all n, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}|$ converges by the comparison test. Correct? But I have trouble proving the inequality, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab =(a+b)^2 \geq 0,$$
meaning $a^2 + b^2 \geq  -2ab$

$$a^2 + b^2 -2ab = (a-b)^2\geq 0,$$
therefore $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2ab$.

Conclusion: $a^2 + b^2 \geq 2|ab|$